# Segfault when using signalhandlers while writing a basic shell in c

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault, signals

So, I am writing a basic shell in C and need to have signal-handlers.

Detection of terminated background process should be implemented by two mechanisms where one selects which should be compiled at compilation time. The mechanisms are ordinary polling and detection by signals sent from the child processes. The user should be able to select which mechanism to use by defining a macro `SIGDET=1` at compilation time to have termination detected by signals. If SIGDET is undefined or equals zero then termination should be detected by polling.

I need to compile using `gcc -pedantic -Wall -ansi -O4`
When I call on my program using `cc -pedantic -Wall -ansi -O4 main.c -o shell -DSIGDET=1 && ./shell`, then run a short background-process (for example, `sleep 2 &`), it gives me a segfault. I don't know why, can someone help me?

Execute is a function that takes the commands, `fork()` and then in child uses `execvp`.

**EDIT: Got a few questions:**

`parser()` returns the amount of commands that is put in, for example `sleep 3 &` returns 3. `r[size-1] = NULL` removes the last command, but only if it is `&`. That is because I don't want to send it to execute, I only need to know it's supposed to run in the background.

**EDIT: Print Out:**

`background` immediately after putting in a command with `&`.
Then it prints out the `OUTSIDE LOOP` message, before it prints a segfault and then exits.

**EDIT: With -g flag and running gdb**

I run debug, and I get the following:

```
>: sleep 2 &
background
>: OUTSIDE LOOP: 11661 with this status: 0
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7aa0ad9 in strtok () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

I am not doing anything weird with strtok(), it's only used in the parser and it is as follows:

```
int parser(char * input, char ** r)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *tokens = strtok(input, DELIM);
    /* char r[40]; */

    while(tokens) 
    {
        r[i] = tokens;
        tokens = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
        i++;
    }
    r[i] = NULL;
    return i;
}
```

Heres sort of my code (excluding parsing and execute-functions and such):

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for getcwd */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc */
#include <signal.h>
#include "functions.h"
#include "textfunc.h"
#include "textfunc.c"
#include "functions.c"

#define MAX_LENGTH 80
#define DELIM " \n\r\t"

typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);

void sig(int signal)
{
  int status;
  pid_t pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
  printf(" OUTSIDE LOOP: %d with this status: %d\n", pid, status);
}

int main()
{
  char *input;
  char * r[40];
  int size;

  signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN); /* */

  #if SIGDET==1
  signal(SIGCHLD, sig); 
  #endif

  while(1)
  {
    int bg = -1;

    #if SIGDET!=1
    int status;
    pid_t pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
    if(pid > 0)
      printf("INSIDE LOOP: %d with this status: %d\n", pid, status);
    #endif

    prompt();

    input = readInput();
    size = parser(input, r);

    if(r[0] == NULL)
        continue;
    else if(strcmp("&", r[size-1]) == 0)
    {
      printf("background\n");
      r[size-1] = NULL;
      bg = 0;
    }
    if(strcmp("exit", r[0]) == 0)
        {
        kill(0, SIGKILL);
      }
    else if(strcmp("cd", r[0]) == 0)
      changedir(r[1]);
    else if(strcmp("checkEnv", r[0]) == 0)
      checkenv(r);
    else
    {
        execute(&input, r, bg);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `r[size-1] = NULL;` scares me... what is `size` when `size = parser(input, r);`

Comment: Do you have a backtrace from the crash?

Comment: it would be interesting to know if "background" were printed before the crash...

Comment: @polarysekt edited the question so it answers your question, but in short: i use `size` to see the amount of commands, remove the `&` if there is one. also, `background` is printed.

Comment: I missed the type of r. `char * r[40]` Would `r[size-1][0] = '\0';` work?

Comment: I get the error `sleep: invalid time interval '' ` where the last thing is two single qoutation-marks. then it prints the `OUTSIDE LOOP`-message before segfaulting.

Comment: Note: don't use printf() and friends inside a signal handler. They are not signal safe.

Comment: I know I should not use "printf()", but it makes no difference if I remove it (still segfault) and it's currently really only used for debugging to see if it does somewhat right. :(

Comment: Yes, that's the hard stuff: having more than one error in a progam. And not knowing whom to blame.

Comment: I, while using gdb (which should be compiled with '-ggdb', not just '-g'  because then it produces a max amount of info specifically for the gdb debugger.

Comment: have you checked, upon entry to 'parse()' that parameter 'r' contains the address of 'r'?

Comment: these two line: 'typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);' are defined in the signal.h file, so should not be in your source file

Comment: have you checked that the string pointed to by 'input' is NUL ('\0') terminated?

Comment: the list of delimiters probably should include a space, a comma, a semicolon, and a few other key delimiters that the user might normally enter   I also do not see where parens, braces, '&&', '||' and other normal command line delimiters are being handled.

Comment: regarding this line: 'else if(strcmp("&", r[size-1]) == 0)'  Suggest having the called functions look for that, as part of their parameter processing (they can, for now, always ignore that directive

Comment: this line: 'if(r[0] == NULL)' is depending on the data contents.  Suggest using 'if( 0 == size )' as a reason to jump back to the top of the loop

Comment: when using the signaling feature, the main loop is going to be spending most of its' time waiting for the user to input a command line.  if not using the signaling feature, then the main loop is going to be spending most of its' time in the waitpid() function.   Is this the operation you are looking for?  Why is the signal handler performing a waitpid()?   That is like 'closing the barn door after that horse has ran away.

Comment: should the main() function be calling 'signal()' when #if SIGDET!=1?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the man page for 'signal()'  which, in part says:

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also
>   var‐
>          ied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use:
>          use sigaction(2) instead.

Please note the part about using sigaction() rather than signal()